# rake error cannot find rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Hello I am working on a rails application and every time I try to run any rake command I get this error

**/usr/local/bin/rake:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/rake:22:in`'**
 I am not sure what it means and I could use some guidance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you done:
`gem install rake` ?

Comment: or, because I see this looks like a *nix box -- `apt-get install rake` or similar for your platform?

Comment: Yes to both answers. I am using rake 11.2.2 and rake 10.5.0 if that helps. I didn't have a problem with rake until I upgraded from Ubuntu 15 to 16.

Comment: Just for funsies -- have you tried reinstalling the packages? perhaps something went awry during the upgrade or a package has a new dependency which wasn't properly specified (and thus installed) at upgrade time? Because the error looks like Ruby saying "I can't load that extension, sir" -- which would happen if the gem were missing, corrupt or had a dependency which was missing.

Comment: Okay so I had help from a friend and now I have to use bundle exec if I want to use rake. I am still not sure why I have the error with just the rake command alone, because I should get a message telling me to use bundle exec but at least its working now thank you all for the assistance.

Comment: You're welcome; pity I didn't actually give you any useful info ):

Comment: Hello @user3780080, why don't you answer your own question? This is encouraged here on SO because it will help also others with the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem with

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/rake /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/
```

See https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/pull/477/commits/e5909f11b6de405d9a26191d154f1b650f6f8b41

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error was:

> .../bin/rake:29:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/exe/rake (LoadError)

I've fixed it removing the specification file that should not be there:

```
rm /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/rake-12.3.1.gemspec
```

Seems that `rubygems` looks for the executable in '../exe/rake', so it fails when it's not there (as rake is installed somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was  `gem uninstall rake` and `gem install rake` now it works :|

overcame this

Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>' /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in` load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake (LoadError)